# How to make an image always load in the center of page?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make webpage with image that have products in the center. but the product gets cut off and i have to scroll down to see the whole image.

How can you make it load so the image is center?

**in the body**

```
<img alt="The Argan Tree Product Line" src="images/products2.jpg" id="bgimage" class="mainimage"/>
```

**css for element**

```
#bgimage{
  z-index: -999;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
min-width:960px;
min-height:720px;
}
```

I am using this jquery to make the image change size when browser is different sizes

```
$(document).ready(function()
{   
    if ($(document).height() < (.75 * $(document).width())){
        var wide = $(document).width();
        if (wide>960){
        $("#bgimage").css("min-width", wide + "px");
        var high = .75 * $(document).width();
        $("#bgimage").css("min-height", high + "px");
        $("#content-wrapper").css("width", wide +"px");
        $("#content-wrapper").css("height", high +"px");
    }
    }

    if ($(document).height() >= (.75 * $(document).width())){
        var high = $(document).height();
        if (high>720){
        var wide = 1.33 * high;
        $("#content-wrapper").css("width", wide +"px");
        $("#content-wrapper").css("height", high +"px");
    }
```

**More code here for clicking effects(remove for this question...too much code!)**

```
}
    $(window).resize(function()
    {
        if ($(window).height() < (.75 * $(window).width())){
            var wide = $(window).width();
            if (wide>960){
            $("#bgimage").css("min-width", wide + "px");
            var high = .75 * wide;
            $("#bgimage").css("min-height", high + "px");
            $("#content-wrapper").css("width", wide +"px");
            $("#content-wrapper").css("height", high +"px");
            }
        }

        if ($(document).height() >= (.75 * $(document).width())){
            var high = $(document).height();
            if (high>720){
            var wide = 1.33 * high;
            $("#content-wrapper").css("width", wide +"px");
            $("#content-wrapper").css("height", high +"px");
            }
            }



    });
```

Thank you!!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#bgimage { 
   display:block;
   width:100%;
   max-width:100%;
   height:auto;
   margin:0px auto;
   position:relative;
   min-width:960px;
   min-height:720px;
}
```

Using this method, the image will be centered and fluid (so it will automatically adjust based on your browser or container size).

If your screen/browser window is smaller than 960x720, then you have to remove those minimum properties and let it be fluid.  The container that `#bgimage` is inside can also determine this maximum/minimum size with these properties.

Also, instead of a lot of JS, you can use [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) to adjust sizes based on the window, too.

```
@media all and (max-width:960px) {

     #bgimage { 
        display:block;
        width:100%;
        max-width:100%;
        height:auto;
        margin:0px auto;
        position:relative;
        min-width:480px;
        min-height:360px;
    }



}
```

Comment: thank you, so i should remove min height and min width? if i do that nothing seem to change :(

Comment: it depends.  If you take out the mins, then the image is fluid and adjusts based on its window size.  for example (http://jsfiddle.net/7YhX5/) the image is naturally 1900x1200, but because of the CSS it scales to the window (notice when you adjust the window size).  So if you absolutely want that image to fit, then I would just use the 100% width and remove the minimums.

Answer (score 0):

```
#bgimage {    
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: px ore %;
    }
```